# Spring dataflow not responding after deploy

Tags: java, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-data-flow

I tried to do a deployment for some applications in spring dataflow,
Routinely each diploi takes a few minutes and passes successfully or fails.
But this time the diplomacy took longer than usual. At one point I pressed "undeploy"
Since the system does not respond.
Under Stream all flickers in UNKNOWN mode.
It is not possible to redeploy.
When I try to perform a dipole I get the error `Failed to upload the package. Package [test-orders:1.0.0] in Repository [local] already exists.` from the ui

When I request the status of the pods I get 2 pods with `CrashLoopBackOff` status

- I rebooted all pods `kubectl -n ****  rollout restart deploy`
- I try to run `dataflow:>stream undeploy --name test-orders`
- I deleted the new docker image from EKS
- Changed skipper_status from FAILED to DELETED

The problem still exists.

I'm really at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,
I seem to have been able to solve the problem.

Due to the CrashLoopBackOff status I realized that the system is unable to pull the image or the image is corrupt.

I have overwritten all the images in EKS that are associated with the project.

I changed the problematic `skipper_status.status_code` to `DELETED`(`update skipper_status set status_code = 'DELETED' where id =***`).

In the skipper_release table I added

```
backoffLimit: 6
completions: 1
parallelism: 1
```

So a crash of the system after several attempts will result in the end of a run.
I did a reset for all the pods.

And then in the UI interface I pressed the undeploy button.

**Edit 1**

I noticed that there were pods left that did not close.
I closed them like this:
`kubectl -n foobar delete deployment foo-bar-v1`